# how to determine which version of enterprise library a dll came from?

Tags: enterprise-library

I have an application using a dll from the 'Microsoft Enterprise Library'.
How do I find out which version of the 'Enterprise library' the dll came from?
The dll is 'Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.ExceptionManagement.dll' and it's
'Product' and 'File'  version is 1.0.3055.29252.

Answer (score 0):

Your assembly is part of [Exception Management Application Block](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8ca8eb6e-6f4a-43df-adeb-8f22ca173e02&displaylang=en).  This was the first release from  4/23/2002 and actually predates the name Enterprise Library.

I think this was released only as source code so your build version doesn't help much.